# Why did S. serrata die?

Tags: aquaculture

We are interested to farm *Scylla serrata* which is a type of crab. We introduced the crab weighing 800 g into a environment with 22 ppt salinity with a pH of 8.2. The crab was feeding on around 12 g of chicken meat daily. However at the end of the 4<sup>th</sup> day, after flipping the crab to its back, it died shortly after. Previously it was able to flip itself back successfully. Note that salinity and pH did not vary much.

What are the possible root causes for death?

Comment: A complete species name would be better